# Ajax Search Table Not Working / Cannot Fetch Data - Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I cannot simply fetch any data on my table, I tried to clean my code but still not working here is my code

**Controller** - I am not sure if this is correct or am i still missing something

```
 function fetch()
  {
    $data  = $this->level_model->fetch_data();

    echo $this->load->view('levels', ['data' => $data], TRUE );
  }
```

**View**

```
<select class='form-input input-lg col-md-6' name="search_text" id="search_text">
     <?php 
       foreach ($courses as $row) {
           echo '<option value="'.$row->course.'">'.$row->course.'</option>';
       }
     ?>
 </select>
```

**Table**

```
     <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%;">
                    <thead> 
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Course</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="showdata">

                    </tbody>
       </table>
```

**Model** - so here where I query so i can match the data and fetch it.

```
 function fetch_data($query)
 {
  $this->db->select("*");
  $this->db->from("levels");
  if($query != '')
  {
   $this->db->like('course_year', $query);
  }
  $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
  return $this->db->get();
 }
```

**AJAX / JAVASCRIPT** I am not quite sure if my ajax is right please kindy check

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     load_data();

     function load_data(query)
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>levels/fetch",
       method:"POST",
       data:{query:query},
       success:function(data){
                 var html = '';
                 var i;
                  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr>'+
                              '<td>'+data[i].course_year+'</td>'+
                              '<td>'+
                              '<a class="btn btn-primary item-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'"" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit  </a> | '+
                              '<a class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'"" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete</a></td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                  }
              $('#showdata').html(html);
           }
      })
     }

     $('#search_text').change(function(){
      var search = $(this).val();
      if(search != '')
      {
       load_data(search);
      }
      else
      {
       load_data();
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: "I cannot simply fetch any data on my table"...why? What error messages do you get? Show your network tab, and investigate why this may be.

Comment: @FrankerZ - there's nothing to show in the network tab, what I have now is I can display the data in the table, but when I fetch or select a data in the select box to search. then that is not working

Comment: are you get data from this $data  = $this->level_model->fetch_data();

Comment: Your fetch_data() method expects a `$query` parameter, but you haven't passed one in the line `$data  = $this->level_model->fetch_data();`. Are you sure, it's not throwing an error?

Comment: this code has lots of php notices and warnings

Answer (score 0):

When the document is loading you are calling the `load_data` function without passing value to the `query` parameter here.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     load_data();
```

You should give it a default value here like this

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     load_data();

     function load_data(query='')
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>levels/fetch",
       method:"POST",
       data:{query:query},
       success:function(data){
                 var html = '';
                 var i;
                  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    html += '<tr>'+
                              '<td>'+data[i].course_year+'</td>'+
                              '<td>'+
                              '<a class="btn btn-primary item-edit" data="'+data[i].id+'"" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit  </a> | '+
                              '<a class="btn btn-danger item-delete" data="'+data[i].id+'"" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Delete</a></td>'+
                            '</tr>';
                  }
              $('#showdata').html(html);
           }
      })
     }

     $('#search_text').change(function(){
      var search = $(this).val();
      if(search != '')
      {
       load_data(search);
      }
      else
      {
       load_data();
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Also you are not passing any data to your model .

```
function fetch()
{
    $data  = $this->level_model->fetch_data(
                 $_POST['query'];
             );

    echo $this->load->view('levels', ['data' => $data], TRUE );
}
```

Comment: good day! I tried your updated code, I also updated my code above I added the table id. please see. as of now it cant still fetch any data

Comment: @codeislife  have you var dumped `$data` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your controller `fetch` method as below:

```
function fetch()
{
    $data  = $this->level_model->fetch_data(
                 $this->input->post('query');
             );

    echo $this->load->view('levels', ['data' => $data], TRUE );
}
```